# Regex similar to Windows 8 Search

Tags: regex

In the Windows 8 search, when I type 'vis stu', **Vis**ual **Stu**dio is matched. I'd like to write a regular expression that does something similar.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simply append a `[a-z]*` at the end of each word. So, `vis stu` would become `vis[a-z]* stu[a-z]*` and hence match:

1. `visual studio`
2. `visual student`
3. `vis stu`

**[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wM4oT5)**

P.S. However, you will need to deal with complicated cases like 'Visual Studio 5' by adding `i`gnore-case flag and a `(?:.*)` at the end to match any extra letters that follow the main part.